# Spring MVC - change security settings dynamically

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on a Java Spring MVC application and I'm using Java based configuration for Spring Security. **I need to change some Spring Security settings dynamically (during user activity)**. This is a part of my code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

         http
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/admin/login")
            ...

}
```

I need to change `/admin/login` url to `customer/login` for example, during user activity.

Comment: @AlanHay I need to change `expiredUrl` dynamically based on some conditions. In the other words, in `condition1` I want to **when a user's session times out**,  redirect him to `/x1/login`, and in `condition2` I want to redirect him to `/x2/login`. In the current settings, when user's session times out, spring redirects him to `/x1/login`(default login page). Could you please help me?

Comment: The configuration referred to in your question is at a global level rather than a per user level so I can't see how changing that is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply provide to links in the HTML, one for customers, one for admins :)

But I guess you wouldn't have asked if this would be a valid solution for you. Depending on how much fun you have coding a little workaround, you could go for this approach:

- Create an anonymous session for your users to remember the users' last activity category. If spring-security cannot (easily) do the job for you, just store the acitivity category in a cookie. Now you could go for solution (1) or (2).

  1. Based on the information you have stored, you could dynamically decide which target login url you render into your HTML pages. This way you could dynamically link the correct login page.
  2. The disadvantage of solution (1) is, that you would have to set the correct target url in each of your controllers, based on the stored value. Maybe a better approach would be to let your HTML always point to the same login-dispatcher controller and forward the request to the correct login page, based on the stored activity category.